# Blender Mesh to UE4: Correct normals but missing faces

Tags: normals

i have imported the following Blender Mesh as a fbx into UE4 getting the following result. The Mesh might have some incorrect normals, but the result I get in UE4 implies way more incorrect normals then there seem to be. Does anyone have a hint for me ?

[image: Blender Mesh]

[image: UE4 Result of Blender Mesh]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have Normals facing in the right direction, but still get some missing faces in UE. Here's some solutions:

- Try to **Triangulate** your Mesh in Blender (Add Modifier >> General >> Triangulate) and then Export it.
- **Apply all Transformations** in Blender before exporting your model (in Object Mode, go to the Object >> Apply >> All Transforms)

By the way, you can also disable [Backface Culling in Blender](https://www.katsbits.com/codex/backface-culling/) to be able to see your model without displaying Normals direction or color.

You can also [activate double-sided Materials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAvV3fOHrLk) in Unreal Engine, but it will slightly reduce performance (depending upon the mesh itself).

Hope it helps!